# How are JavaScript objects converted to strings when using string addition?

Tags: javascript

When I log something like `console.log('' + {});` the console would print `[Object object]` in Chrome, but something different (`{}`) in node. At this point I would have thought that the console output depends on the execution environment.

However, recently I discovered that, given some **not-null** object `foo`, I somehow had Chrome print `null` instead of the expected output above. So using `console.log('' + foo);` resulted in `null` in the console. How is that possible? My first guess was that I must have overridden something important accidentally, like some `toString()` method. Otherwise I could not explain why Chrome would interpret some not-null object as `null` when it is added to a string.

Does anyone know how that implicit object-to-string conversion actually works? It is not that this is a show-stopper, but it really makes me wonder.

**Edit:** I did not include a JSFiddle because this occurs in some quite dependency-heavy class, so there is no proper minimal working example I could offer you. The question does not refer to my code anyway, it is rather basic and technical.

**Another edit:** For the sake of completeness, I am adding the [screenshot](http://s8.postimg.org/ty5pxj3n9/null_string_conversion.png) I posted in the comments.

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle?

Comment: Why the downvote? A comment would have been nice. As for the jsFiddle, no, unfortunately not. The work is still undisclosed. The way I formulated the question I do not think it would be helpful, anyway.

Comment: One reason why you should always create a minimal working example for this kind of problems: In the process of creating the example you most likely find the reason for the problem.

Comment: If you are going to make a claim like "non-null object prints out null", you should provide some evidence that this takes place.

Comment: I did not come here to argue about such things. My point is that when I do console.log(foo === null ? 'It is null' : foo); at some point the object is print out, just as I would have expected. console.log('' + (foo === null ? 'It is null' : foo)); prints null instead, and my question was how that is technically possible. I would not have come here if it wasn't true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked about object to string conversion: [Object.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

If you use objects in string concatenation expressions it will call the object's `toString()` function. You can implement your own function, which could cause the problem you described:

```
function Foo(bar){
  this.bar = bar;
}
Foo.prototype.toString = function fooToString(){
    return this.bar;
};

console.log('' + new Foo(null)); // null
```

Without seeing any code I guess it's this or it's really just the String `"null"`. You said you already checked the `toString` function, but to make sure you could also print it at runtime with `foo.toString.toSource()`. Or just run the object through a debugger and inspect it.

Comment: Thank you very much, your confirmation that toString() was the right thing to look at actually got me a bit further, but on the other hand, now I am completely confused: "'' + foo" evaluates to "null". "'' + foo.toString()'' evalutes to "[Object object]". When I override toString(), this remains the same. Since in JSFiddle this works just well, I think it is some dependency messing around with the interpreter I can hardly imagine, since toString() does not seem to get called at all in this specific case.

Comment: I will accept this answer since it really answers the question: How are JavaScript objects converted to strings when using string addition?

Comment: I actually thought your idea of using the debugger was nice for taking a screenshot of this oddity: http://s8.postimg.org/ty5pxj3n9/null_string_conversion.png The behavior is the same in both the latest Chrome and Firefox versions.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the difference is simply in how the different environments choose to represent an object as a string in the console. They both mean the same thing, namely that the thing you're logging is an object. You might see a further difference if you tested in the developer tools in Firefox or Safari.

In your second example, I suspect the value of `foo` is null - I just can't think of a situation in which the statement `console.log('' + foo)` would print `null` if the value of `foo` wasn't set to `null` or, as Xymostech says in the comments, set to the string `null`.

Comment: No offense, but I even wrote not-null in bold. The object is not null! console.log(foo) !== console.log('' + foo). The first lets me inspect the object, the second prints null. Please read the question properly.

Comment: None taken Michael, and I did read the question. I just can't think of a situation in which the statement console.log('' + foo) would print null if foo wasn't null.

Comment: Alright then. Well, this is exactly why I came up with this question. Just to give one more example: console.log('' + (foo === null ? 'Oh noes, it's null!' : foo)); prints null, too. This was the first thing I did, but it can only occur when foo is *not* null.

Comment: @MichaelJess Was `foo` by any chance the string, `'null'`?

Comment: I think there's something wrong with that log statement in your comment. Try changing it to console.log(foo === null ? 'Oh no' : foo);

Comment: You mean the string addition? No, that's just fine. As I said, this is exactly what the question refers to: The string conversion of objects when they are 'added to' strings. Your suggestions is just equivalent to console.log(foo), which is not am looking for.

Comment: @Xymostech Thanks for the guess, but no, it is some Backbone.View subtype. It really is an object, and it is not null.

Comment: The statement you've posted in the comment isn't valid. I take it it's just a typo rather than an error in your code?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet Why is it invalid?

Comment: Paste it into the console and try running it. Have  a look at this - http://jsfiddle.net/bq7F5/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to escape a quote. It's console.log('' + (foo === null ? 'Oh noes, it\'s null!' : foo));, and that just runs fine.

Comment: Dunno then ;). I think I'm out.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet Thank you for trying to help, though! I appreciate that very much.